# How would I limit the # of search results to 10 with each item added into an array removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have created a for loop to limit my list to only show last 10 search results but can't seem to shift() index[0] of the object array off so earliest results are deleted and latest results are at the end of the array:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < searchHistory.length; i++) {
  if (searchHistory.length > 10) {
    console.log(searchHistory[i]);
    searchHistory[i].shift();
  }
}
```

The console.log of searchHistory = [Object Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c1bk.png)

The console.log of searchHistory[i] = [Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcWvQ.png)

Comment: The question and the title are asking two separate things. Please edit this to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to limit the length of an array you don't need a loop; `slice()` can do it for you:

```
searchHistory = searchHistory.slice(-10);
```

Note that this also removes the need for the `if` condition.

Comment: I am trying to limit the array but my problem seems to be getting the value of the object in the first place >.<

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean there. To get the `city` value of the objects either loop through them, or access individually by index, eg. `searchHistory[0].city`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Rory but that's why I had the for loop >.< When I run my code I get the following error :(  "Uncaught TypeError: searchHistory[i].shift is not a function"

Comment: Because the property name is `city`, not `shift`.

Comment: I get the same error when written as searchHistory.city.shift() where the .shift() was to remove the first element in the array..?

Comment: Why are you still calling `shift()`? It's not relevant to the issue as I've explained in the answer and previous comments. For one thing it needs to be called on the array itself, not the objects within it, and secondly it removes the first element from the array and returns it, this is irrelevant to your goal of returning the first 10 elements of that array.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself since I'm new at this, but didn't comprehend your answer or previous comments either; Will ask my instructor tomorrow as you're coming off a bit frustrated answering a new coder's questions...

Answer (score 0):

To limit your array to the last 10 elements use:

```
searchHistory.slice(-10);
```

So to display the last 10 use:

```
if( searchHistory.length > 10 ) {
    searchHistory.slice(-10).forEach(s => console.log( s ));
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
    const searchHistory = [4,5,6,67,32,1,3,4,5,9,10,12,13,4,66,67,78,90];
    //Display the last 10 all at once - array
    console.log( searchHistory.slice(-10) );
    
    //Display last 10, one at a time
    if( searchHistory.length > 10 ) {
        searchHistory.slice(-10).forEach(s => console.log( s ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice() to limit the number items you want

Comment: Welcome to SO! As it is currently written, your answer is unclear. Please edit it and add more details why and how it works. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.